# Wording not appearing on button in HTML/ CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a footer in HTML/CSS and I am trying to create an email form at the bottom of the footer. I have already created the button and form itself; however, the wording on the button does not appear.

Here is my HTML code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: #212329;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer-container h4 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px gray;
}

.footer-container h6 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px gray;
}

.footer-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.footer-heading h6 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.footer-heading a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.footer-heading a:hover {
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.email-form h4 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#footer-email {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#footer-email::placeholder {
  color: #b1b1b1;
}

#footer-email-btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: darkred;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#footer-email-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-container">
  <h4>Golden Lion Insurance Services</h4>
  <div class="footer-heading">
    <h6>About Golden Lion</h6>
    <a href="#">About Rose</a>
    <a href="#">Rose Income Tax Services</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-heading">
    <h6>Services</h6>
    <a href="#">Auto</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Truck</a>
    <a href="#">Health</a>
    <a href="#">Commercial</a>
    <a href="#">Life</a>
    <a href="#">Bonds</a>
    <a href="#">Annuities</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-heading">
    <h6>Resources</h6>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-heading">
    <h6>Contact Us</h6>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-heading"></div>
  <div class="email-form">
    <h4>Get Your Latest Insurance Tips from Us!</h4>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" id="footer-email">
    <button type="submit" value="Sign Up!" id="footer-email-btn"></button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Perhaps I may have missed some coding on the CSS, but the wording "sign up!" doesn't appear when I launch the code on my browser (I am using the current version of Google Chrome). Any help or pointers?

Thanks again!

Comment: Is the last footer-heading class closed with no content on purpose?

Comment: Put the words "Sign Up!" between the opening and closing tags of the button.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem seems to be in your HTML file on the 3rd line from the bottom.
When you declare a button, you need to mention some innerText in it.

For Example: `<button> innerText </button>`

Similarly for your code:

```
<button type="submit" value="Sign Up!" id="footer-email-btn">Sign Up!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No worries, you only need to add some text inside the bottom tag.

Update your HTML button tag as the following

```
<button type="submit" value="Sign Up!" id="footer-email-btn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button